# console.log (Marketo Munchkin) appeared on my drive

Tags: security, logging, cookies

I hope this is the right place for this question, help me if not!

I just noticed that in my root folder on my E: drive, which is NOT my system (Windows 10) partition where programs are installed but only a data storage, an unwanted file has appeared: "console.log".

This is its content:

```
> Message: Munchkin.init("%s") options:
> 
> Source: http://munchkin.marketo.net/160/munchkin.js
> 
> Line: 22
> 
> -----------------------
> 
> Message: Munchkin.init("%s") options:
> 
> Source: http://munchkin.marketo.net/160/munchkin.js
> 
> Line: 22
> 
> -----------------------
> 
> Message: Munchkin.init("%s") options:
> 
> Source: http://munchkin.marketo.net/160/munchkin.js
> 
> Line: 22
> 
> -----------------------
```

I've tried googling, but I seem to find only explanations for developers which are trying to *use* this Munchkin which I have no idea what it is!

Actually I have found [this request](https://community.adobe.com/t5/exchange-discussions/adobe-munchkin-tracking/td-p/11332943) for support from Adobe, the guy has an identical issue and he seems convinced it's from one of their software. But he got no useful answer.

Nobody else seems to have my problem. I'm really upset for this file appearing from nowhere, in a "cold" partition of my hard disk! Does anyone happen to know what's going on?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the explanation and solution for the appearance of the console.log file created by SketchUp:

https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/sketchup-console-log.html

**tl;dr:**
There's an (outdated) chromium based webbrowser integrated in the SketchUp Launcher which throws this errors. You can disable it by simply renaming the file 'sketchup_webhelper.exe' in your SketchUp program folder, so that it cannot be started anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the culprit! It's SketchUp: as soon as I open a file (which is in my data partition) the file console.log is created.

The only appearance of this issue on Google seems to be [this one](https://forums.sketchup.com/t/stop-automatic-console-log-texts-being-saved-to-my-computer/163599). And, it seems to provide no useful solution to the problem.

I can live with it, now that I know that it's (probably) not malware-related, but I'll be grateful to anyone who suggests a way to stop this from happening.